# Could wrapping a loop in a try-catch block cause performance problems?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

In a game or some other application where an infinite loop would be used, could wrapping the loop in a `try`-`catch` block be a detriment to performance?

Something like this:

```
auto main() -> int{
    game::init();

    try{
        while(1){
            some_func();
            some_other_func();

            if(breaking_func())
                break;

            something_that_could_throw(); // unlikely, though

            draw();
            swap_buffers();
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception &err){
        // do error handling
    }

    game::cleanup();
}
```

I tagged `gcc`, but any other compilers would also be applicable.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the code or anything to see what happens?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner not possible right now, but I will when I get the chance

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Why is it "not possible right now"? You should take the time to do it _before asking us_. If that means you have to wait a while, then so be it. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because I'm not at home and I'm interested

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah, I was going about to close as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: At the risk of sounding rude, that's not really our problem..

Comment: -1 No research effort has been shown. Question does not add to the repository or present additional value to the kinship. </under_the_dome>

Comment: @CoffeeandCode The answer to that question answers yours too (even though the question is slightly different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wrapping the loop in a `try {} catch() {}` block, will give you a small performance hit when the `try {}` block is entered, but not for execution of the individual iterations in the loop.

Vs. a non wrapped version, entering the `try { }` block requires the compiler to emit some additional instructions to be able entering the defined `catch() {}` blocks coming after. These additional instructions will have a (very small) performance difference vs. an unwrapped loop.

Even, if the `try {} catch() {}` would be applied to the inner part of the loop, the overhead for installing the `catch() {}` block entry points will be applied only once, and not for individual iterations.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Why does entering the `try` block incur a performance hit and why is there none for the execution of the loop?

Comment: @Walter Because some entry point(s) for the `catch() {}` blocks for stack unwinding in case of thrown exceptions need to be installed.

Comment: I agree with @Walter; this answer could do with some fleshing out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Giving the best from my nexus10 ;-) ...